# Confusion about spin in 1 dimension

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, fermions, spinors, bosons

If spin should not be defined for particles in 1 dimension since we can't do rotations in 1d, like it happens for the orbital angular momentum, then why can we talk about fermions in a 1 dimensional box for example? Do we mean that if we take two fermions and constrain them to 1 dimension, they preserve their spin? But then in which cases do we have particles in 1 dimension that have no spin, if we can always think of them as fermions/bosons (i.e. with spin) constrained to 1 dimension?

Comment: The fermions anticommute, even though they have no well-defined spin.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks, but could you explain a little more what do you mean by that in terms of a first introductory course in qm? By anticommute do you mean that 2 fermions must be represented by an antisymmetric state right? But isn't that related with the fact that they have non-integer spin?

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, there is no rotation group in 1 dimension. Spin must obey the same Lie algebra/group as angular momentum. You cannot have it in a dimensionality that cannot support the other.

So there is nothing to undergird the [spin statistics theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem#Relation_to_representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group), which is valid for 3 dimensions (extending to some selective  [higher dimensions](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10773-007-9448-5) ). The proof is subtle, and I gather this is not what you are after here.

One-dimensional fermions anticommute, and have nothing to do with their ill-defined spin. Anticommutation is not inexorably linked to spin; in 3D it happens to be.

Comment: Thank you, but why do 1d fermions anticommute if they don't have spin? Furthermore, if we constrain a 1d fermion in a 1d system, can't we measure its spin with some experiments? Is it right to think that a particle acquires its spin only in more dimensions, like the orbital angular moentum? But then why in more dimensions we get the dinstinction between fermions and bosons? What I don't understand is that if spin is an intrinsic property of a particle, how can it disappear in 1d? I mean, what happens to a fermion/boson in 1d?